# Single quotes are not working properly in XeLaTeX for Bengali language

Tags: xetex, quoting

Please see MWE below:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
% For a bilingual document
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\RequirePackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
% Times New Roman used for English
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=Devanagari]{bengali}
\setotherlanguage{english}
% Bengali
\newfontfamily\bengalifont[Script=Bengali,AutoFakeBold=4.0,AutoFakeSlant=0.4]{SolaimanLipi}
\newfontfamily\bengalifontbf[Script=Bengali,AutoFakeBold=4.0,AutoFakeSlant=0.4]{SolaimanLipi}
\newfontfamily\bengalifontsf[Script=Bengali,AutoFakeBold=4.0,AutoFakeSlant=0.4]{SolaimanLipi}
\title{LaTeX  ইংলিশ ডকুমেন্টে বাংলা বোল্ড এবং ইটালিক ফন্ট লেখাটি কীভাবে লিখবেন?}
\author{MKS}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
`সাধারন  স্টাইল',   \textbf{বোল্ড  ফন্ট স্টাইল }, \textit{ইটালিক ফন্ট স্টাইল । }
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Single quotes not working in Bengali. What to do to work properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems here: `polyglossia` is making `` ` `` active, and I suspect that the font you selected (you do not say which of several with similar names you were using) does not contain smart quotes at all.  The most-likely match I could find does not.

Entering the Unicode characters `‘` and `’`, and selecting a font that has the characters, makes that part of it work.  However, many Bengali fonts lack the Devanagari numerals you requested.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\tracinglostchars=2
% For a bilingual document
\RequirePackage{polyglossia}
\defaultfontfeatures{ Ligatures=TeX, Scale=MatchUppercase }
% Times New Roman used for English
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setmainlanguage{bengali}
\setotherlanguage{english}

% Bengali
\newfontfamily\bengalifont{NotoSerifBengali}[
  Script=Bengali,
  Language=Bengali,
  AutoFakeBold = 0.2,
  AutoFakeSlant = 0.15  ]
\title{\textenglish{LaTeX}  ইংলিশ ডকুমেন্টে বাংলা বোল্ড এবং ইটালিক ফন্ট লেখাটি কীভাবে লিখবেন?}
\author{\textenglish{MKS}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
‘সাধারন  স্টাইল’,   \textbf{বোল্ড  ফন্ট স্টাইল}, \textit{ইটালিক ফন্ট স্টাইল । }
\end{document}
```

if you do want to use this particular font, in XeLaTeX, you could in theory use `ucharclasses` to take Bangla from one font, Latin and punctuation from another, and Devanagari from a third.

Comment: @ Davislor Many thanks to you for solving my problem. You have been given the  up vote as credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Using expl3 regex and replace functions, for xelatex or lualatex, as a sort of manual way of doing the `ucharclasses` functionality mentioned in @Davislor 's comment.

[image: quotes and digits]

The colours are just for testing, to show that the glyphs are coming in from different fonts.

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
% For a bilingual document
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
% Times New Roman used for English
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=Bengali,
changecounternumbering=true]{bengali}
\setotherlanguage{english}
%Punctuation (quotes) source:
\newfontfamily\ftpunct{Times New Roman}[Colour=red]%for testing
%Digits
\newfontfamily\ftdigits{Noto Sans Devanagari}[Colour=blue]%for testing
% Bengali
\newfontfamily\bengalifont[Script=Bengali,AutoFakeBold=4.0,AutoFakeSlant=0.4]{Kalpurush}%SolaimanLipi}
\newfontfamily\bengalifontbf[Script=Bengali,AutoFakeBold=4.0,AutoFakeSlant=0.4]{Kalpurush}%SolaimanLipi}
\newfontfamily\bengalifontsf[Script=Bengali,AutoFakeBold=4.0,AutoFakeSlant=0.4]{Kalpurush}%SolaimanLipi}SolaimanLipi}
\title{LaTeX  ইংলিশ ডকুমেন্টে বাংলা বোল্ড এবং ইটালিক ফন্ট লেখাটি কীভাবে লিখবেন?}
\author{MKS}


%========================
\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l_myxuchar_tl 
\tl_new:N \l_myxucharb_tl 
\NewDocumentEnvironment{xuchare}{ +b }
{ 
                  \tl_set:Nn \l_myxuchar_tl  { #1 }
                    \doxuchar
                    \tl_use:N \l_myxuchar_tl 
}{}
\NewDocumentCommand{\xuchar}{ m }
{ 
                  \tl_set:Nn \l_myxucharb_tl  { #1 }
                    \doxucharb
                    \tl_use:N \l_myxucharb_tl 
}{}

\newcommand\doxuchar{
                    \regex_replace_all:nnN %opening quote
                                        { 
                                                ([\`]+)
                                                ([ঀ-৿]{1})   % Bengali glyphs: 0980 to 09FF
                                                }                                       
                                        { 
                                            \cB\{ 
                                            \c{formatquotes}
                                            \1  
                                            \cE\} 
                                            \2
                                            } 
                                        \l_myxuchar_tl 
                    \regex_replace_all:nnN %closing quote
                                        { 
                                                ([ঀ-৿]{1})   % Bengali glyphs: 0980 to 09FF
                                                ([\']+)
                                                }                                       
                                        { 
                                            \1  
                                            \cB\{ 
                                            \c{formatquotes}
                                            \2
                                            \cE\} 
                                            } 
                                        \l_myxuchar_tl 
                    %Bengali digits to Devanagari
                    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_myxuchar_tl { ০ } { {\formatdigits ०} }
                    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_myxuchar_tl { ১ } { {\formatdigits १} }
                    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_myxuchar_tl { ২ } { {\formatdigits २} }
                    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_myxuchar_tl { ৩ } { {\formatdigits ३} }
                    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_myxuchar_tl { ৪ } { {\formatdigits ४} }
                    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_myxuchar_tl { ৫ } { {\formatdigits ५} }
                    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_myxuchar_tl { ৬ } { {\formatdigits ६} }
                    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_myxuchar_tl { ৭ } { {\formatdigits ७} }
                    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_myxuchar_tl { ৮ } { {\formatdigits ८} }
                    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_myxuchar_tl { ৯ } { {\formatdigits ९} }
                                         
}

\newcommand\doxucharb{
                    %Bengali digits to Devanagari
            \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_myxucharb_tl { ০ } { {\formatdigits ०} }
            \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_myxucharb_tl { ১ } { {\formatdigits १} }
            \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_myxucharb_tl { ২ } { {\formatdigits २} }
            \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_myxucharb_tl { ৩ } { {\formatdigits ३} }
            \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_myxucharb_tl { ৪ } { {\formatdigits ४} }
            \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_myxucharb_tl { ৫ } { {\formatdigits ५} }
            \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_myxucharb_tl { ৬ } { {\formatdigits ६} }
            \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_myxucharb_tl { ৭ } { {\formatdigits ७} }
            \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_myxucharb_tl { ৮ } { {\formatdigits ८} }
            \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_myxucharb_tl { ৯ } { {\formatdigits ९} }
                                         
}

\date{\exp_args:Ne \xuchar { \today } }


\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\formatquotes{\ftpunct}%switch
\newcommand\formatdigits{\ftdigits}%switch

\AtBeginEnvironment{document}{\begin{xuchare}}
\AfterEndEnvironment{document}{\end{xuchare}}




\begin{document}
\maketitle
`সাধারন  স্টাইল',  ``সাধারন  স্টাইল'', \textbf{বোল্ড  ফন্ট স্টাইল }, \textit{ইটালিক ফন্ট স্টাইল । }

০১২৩৪৫৬৭৮৯

\end{document}
```

---

More detail:

SolaimanLipi font does not have left and right quotes.

Changing to a more up-to-date font, or one with more coverage, is the most optimal solution.

FreeSerif font, for example, has Bengali letters, left and right quotes, and Devanagari digits.

Keeping the original font, and adding in glyphs from other fonts, can be done in several ways.

The `ucharclasses` package for xelatex was designed for this.

A package-less xelatex/lualatex solution is also possible, in several ways.

[image: Example manual methods]

(A) Use expl3 regex commands to replace the grave accent `` and single quote `'` with left and right quotes in the appropriate font.

The implementation in the MWE uses a document-wide environment for the regex, so is somewhat breakable when new combinations of characters are introduced into the document which then happen to unintentionally match the regular expression.

The regex which searches for a grave accent directly followed by any Bengali character looks like this:

```
\regex_replace_all:nnN %opening quote
    { 
      ([\`]+) ([ঀ-৿]{1}) % Bengali glyphs: 0980 to 09FF
    }                                       
    { 
     \cB\{ \c{formatquotes} \1  \cE\} \2 }                        \l_myxuchar_tl
```

(B) Use expl3 replace_all functionality to replace custom unique markup code (`qmnl` and `qmnr` in the example) with the formatted quotes.

The user must type the markup code in the correct position.

The equivalent replace function, producing the left quote (U+2018), looks like this:

```
 % Replace shortcut 
    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_myxuchar_tl { qmnl } { {\formatquotes ^^^^2018 } }
```

(C) Create custom commands (`\qmol` and `\qmor` in the example) which expand to the formatted quotes.

```
\newcommand\qmol{{\formatquotes ^^^^2018}}
```

(D) Create a convenient command (`\qenquote{}`) which applies the two commands from (C) to an argument passed in as a parameter, namely the text to be quoted.

```
\newcommand\qenquote[1]{{\formatquotes ^^^^2018}#1{\formatquotes ^^^^2019}}
```

But much more practical, if a suitable font is available, direct input is possible (E, ‘অ’१ ), and if the quotes are not directly accessible, the `\text...` commands can be used (F) -- this latter either in the base font or formatted with the imported font.

With mixing of fonts, much time can be spent searching for fonts that go together well enough to be usable outside of a designer's context.

[image: Mixing fonts]

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont[Renderer=HarfBuzz]{Kalpurush}%Times New Roman}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=Bengali,
changecounternumbering=true]{bengali}
\setotherlanguage{english}
%Punctuation (quotes) source:
\newfontfamily\ftpunct{Times New Roman}[Colour=red]%for testing
%Digits: Devanagari
\newfontfamily\ftdigits{Noto Sans Devanagari}[Colour=blue]%for testing
% Bengali
\newfontfamily\bengalifont[Renderer=HarfBuzz,Script=Bengali,AutoFakeBold=4.0,AutoFakeSlant=0.4]{Kalpurush}
\newfontface\bfont{\detokenize{Charu_Chandan_3D_Unicode-Regular}}[Extension=.ttf,
Path=C:/Windows/Fonts/,
Renderer=HarfBuzz,
Script=Bengali,
UprightFont=*,]
\newfontfamily\fall{FreeSerif}[Colour=violet]


%========================

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l_myxuchar_tl 
\tl_new:N \l_myxucharb_tl 
\NewDocumentEnvironment{xuchare}{ +b }
{ 
                  \tl_set:Nn \l_myxuchar_tl  { #1 }
                    \doxuchar
                    \tl_use:N \l_myxuchar_tl 
}{}
\NewDocumentCommand{\xuchar}{ m }
{ 
                  \tl_set:Nn \l_myxucharb_tl  { #1 }
                    \doxucharb
                    \tl_use:N \l_myxucharb_tl 
}{}
%------------------------------- print and run #1
\tl_new:N \l_my_tl

\NewDocumentCommand{\cdr}{ m }{%
    \tl_set:Nn \l_my_tl { #1 }
    { \ttfamily\color{blue}
%  \token_to_str:N #1
  \detokenize{#1}
  }
  
  \enspace $\mapsto$ \enspace
  
  \colorbox{ blue!20 }{ \tl_use:N \l_my_tl }
}%

\newcommand\doxuchar{
                    \regex_replace_all:nnN %opening quote
                                        { 
                                                ([\`]+)
                                                ([ঀ-৿]{1})   % Bengali glyphs: 0980 to 09FF
                                                }                                       
                                        { 
                                            \cB\{ 
                                            \c{formatquotes}
                                            \1  
                                            \cE\} 
                                            \2
                                            } 
                                        \l_myxuchar_tl 
                    \regex_replace_all:nnN %closing quote
                                        { 
                                                ([ঀ-৿]{1})   % Bengali glyphs: 0980 to 09FF
                                                ([\']+)
                                                }                                       
                                        { 
                                            \1  
                                            \cB\{ 
                                            \c{formatquotes}
                                            \2
                                            \cE\} 
                                            } 
                                        \l_myxuchar_tl 
 % Replace shortcut 
    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_myxuchar_tl { qmnl } { {\formatquotes ^^^^2018 } }           
    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_myxuchar_tl { qmnr } { {\formatquotes ^^^^2019 } }                                   
                    %Bengali digits to Devanagari
                    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_myxuchar_tl { ০ } { {\formatdigits ०} }
                    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_myxuchar_tl { ১ } { {\formatdigits १} }
                    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_myxuchar_tl { ২ } { {\formatdigits २} }
                    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_myxuchar_tl { ৩ } { {\formatdigits ३} }
                    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_myxuchar_tl { ৪ } { {\formatdigits ४} }
                    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_myxuchar_tl { ৫ } { {\formatdigits ५} }
                    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_myxuchar_tl { ৬ } { {\formatdigits ६} }
                    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_myxuchar_tl { ৭ } { {\formatdigits ७} }
                    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_myxuchar_tl { ৮ } { {\formatdigits ८} }
                    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_myxuchar_tl { ৯ } { {\formatdigits ९} }
                                         
}

\newcommand\doxucharb{
                    %Bengali digits to Devanagari
            \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_myxucharb_tl { ০ } { {\formatdigits ०} }
            \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_myxucharb_tl { ১ } { {\formatdigits १} }
            \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_myxucharb_tl { ২ } { {\formatdigits २} }
            \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_myxucharb_tl { ৩ } { {\formatdigits ३} }
            \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_myxucharb_tl { ৪ } { {\formatdigits ४} }
            \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_myxucharb_tl { ৫ } { {\formatdigits ५} }
            \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_myxucharb_tl { ৬ } { {\formatdigits ६} }
            \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_myxucharb_tl { ৭ } { {\formatdigits ७} }
            \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_myxucharb_tl { ৮ } { {\formatdigits ८} }
            \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_myxucharb_tl { ৯ } { {\formatdigits ९} }
                                         
}

\date{\exp_args:Ne \xuchar { \today } }


\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\formatquotes{\ftpunct}%switch
\newcommand\formatdigits{\ftdigits}%switch
\newcommand\qmol{{\formatquotes ^^^^2018}}
\newcommand\qmor{{\formatquotes ^^^^2019}}
\newcommand\qenquote[1]{{\formatquotes ^^^^2018}#1{\formatquotes ^^^^2019}}

\AtBeginEnvironment{document}{\begin{xuchare}}
\AfterEndEnvironment{document}{\end{xuchare}}

\newcommand\testtext{সাধারন  স্টাইল}
\newcommand\eng[1]{\begin{english}#1\end{english}}


\begin{document}
\eng{Digits:}
০১২৩৪৫৬৭৮৯

\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
\rowcolor{blue!5}
Method & Command & How & Input & Output \\
\hline
A & expl3 regex & find-replace & \textasciigrave  অ\textquotesingle & `অ' \\
B & expl3 replace & find-replace & qmn{}lঅqmn{}r & qmnlঅqmnr \\
C & macros & expand & \textbackslash qmol অ\textbackslash qmor & \qmol অ\qmor \\
D & command & argument & \textbackslash qenquote\{অ\} & \qenquote{অ} \\
E & in font &FreeSerif & direct input: \colorbox{yellow!40}{\fall{^^^^2018অ^^^^2019१}} & \colorbox{yellow!40}{\fall{^^^^2018অ^^^^2019१}} \\
F & commands & kernel & \textbackslash textquoteleft অ\textbackslash textquoteright & \textquoteleft অ\textquoteright \\
\hline
    \end{tabular}

\bigskip
\begin{english}
\cdr{\symbol{39}} \quad quotesingle, {\textquotesingle\small becomes quoteright}

\cdr{\symbol{96}} \quad grave accent, {\textasciigrave\small becomes quoteleft}

\cdr{\symbol{8216}} \quad quoteleft

\cdr{\symbol{8217}} \quad quoteright

\cdr{\symbol{8220}} \quad quotedblleft

\cdr{\symbol{8221}} \quad quotedblright

\cdr{\textquotedblleft}

\cdr{\textquotedblright}

\cdr{\textquotedbl}

\cdr{\textquotesingle}

\cdr{\textasciigrave}

\end{english}


\section{কূল্বনন}
কূল্বনন  {\bfont `\testtext' \eng{versus} `সাধারন  স্টাইল'} \eng{versus} {\bfont `}সাধারন  স্টাইল{\bfont '}

\end{document}
```