# Configuring and auto-correcting the quotation marks in bilingual writing

Tags: xetex, languages, books, csquotes, quotation

I am writing a bilingual (English + Bangla) document with the package `latexbangla`.

(For the following MWE, kindly download the font `Kalpurush` from here: https://www.omicronlab.com/bangla-fonts.html)

````
% !TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[banglamainfont=Kalpurush, banglattfont=Kalpurush]{latexbangla}                               
\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=Bengali, changecounternumbering=true]{bengali}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\begin{document}

\section*{Section 1}
I said,```মানুষ মাত্রই ভুল করে'- এটাকে ইংরেজিতে অনুবাদ কর".\\
He replied, ```To err is human' - It's an easy one. আরো কঠিন কিছু জিজ্ঞেস করেন".

\section*{Section 2}
I said,"'মানুষ মাত্রই ভুল করে'- এটাকে ইংরেজিতে অনুবাদ কর".\\
He replied, "'To err is human' - It's an easy one. আরো কঠিন কিছু জিজ্ঞেস করেন".

\section*{Section 3}
I said,``ইংরেজিতে অনুবাদ কর - `মানুষ মাত্রই ভুল করে'".\\
He replied, ```To err is human' - It's an easy one. আরো কঠিন কিছু জিজ্ঞেস করেন".

\end{document}
````

The output:
[image: The screenshot of the output of my MWE]

Here, Check the red marks where the quotation marks appear wrongly. I want to configure the quotation-mark style to make my `Section 1` and `Section 2` look the same without changing the code inside the sections. Also, check the red mark in my `Section 3`. Before the Bangla text, the double-quote appears as two separate single-quotes. How can I fix these issues? And what can I do to switch from curly to neutral quote-marks everywhere?

Comment: If you  want to keep the TeX mappings, like `He replied, \textquotedbl\textquotesingle To err is human{}\textquotesingle\ - It's an easy one. আরো কঠিন কিছু জিজ্ঞেস করেন\textquotedbl.`? With mappings on, two backticks give left double quote, and one gives left single quote. Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/591300/single-quotes-are-not-working-properly-in-xelatex-for-bengali-language/598036#598036 help?

Comment: I don't want to change anything inside the sections and don't wish to put anything like `textquotebl`. I wanted both `` and " to generate the same quote marks by configuring the quotation style.

Comment: Unrelated: the documentation (`texdoc latexbangla`) mentions that `banglamainfont` and `banglattfont` cannot be the same font.

Comment: But I haven't faced any problem using the same font!

Answer (score 1):

If staying with `latexbangla` is required, then redefining the xetex mappings will do it, such that `` and " will both produce " instead of “ and ” (and likewise, ` and ' will both produce ' instead of ‘ and ’), all the while keeping the other ligatures.

[image: new mappings]

The blue is to highlight the source for the font.

[image: example usage]

Note that to treat single right quote and apostrophe as separate characters (straight versus curly, for example) can be done, but implies markup/code/mapping rules to distinguish them.

Several things need to be done.

(1) Map file

`latexbangla` uses `ucharclasses`, which requires xetex, which in turn can understand mapping files.

Adapting the answer from here
[How does one display straight quotes in the normal font?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43561/how-does-one-display-straight-quotes-in-the-normal-font)  on how to modify the mapping file to keep the other standard ligatures, a copy of `tex-text.map` will have these alternative lines in it:

```
;U+0027         <>  U+2019  ; ' -> right single quote
;U+0027 U+0027  <>  U+201D  ; '' -> right double quote
;U+0022          >  U+201D  ; " -> right double quote

U+0060          <>  U+0027  ; ` -> straight single quote
U+0060 U+0060   <>  U+0022  ; `` -> straight double quote
```

Say the new `.map` file is called `tex-text3.map`. Compiling with `teckit_compile.exe` will produce `tex-text3.tec`, a binary file.

(2) Define mapped fonts

`latexbangla` uses `polyglossia` in the background, which in turn calls `fontspec`.

The `.tec` file is called into play with the `Mapping=` option of a `fontspec` command: e.g., `\newfontfamily\myrmlat[Mapping=tex-text3,Colour=blue]{Noto Serif}` .

(3) Modify `latexbangla` `latin` environment

`latexbangla` defines a `latin` environment with legacy OT1 font encoding (for some reason).

```
\newenvironment{latin}
{\fontencoding{OT1}\ifx\f@family\btt@@name\fontfamily{lmtt}
\else\fontfamily{lmr}\fi\selectfont}\relax
```

Since it is xelatex, we can go Unicode. Xelatex can also understand truetype/opentype fonts anyway, so modern fonts can be used instead, including our mapped fonts (which can be the TTF/OTF versions of `Latin Modern Roman` and `Latin Modern Mono`, if desired).

```
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{latin}
{\ifx\f@family\btt@@name\myttlat
\else\myrmlat\fi}\relax
\makeatother
```

MWE

````
% !TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage[banglamainfont=Kalpurush, banglattfont=Atma]{latexbangla}                               
\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=Bengali, changecounternumbering=true]{bengali}

%\newenvironment{latin}
%{\fontencoding{OT1}\ifx\f@family\btt@@name\fontfamily{lmtt}
%\else\fontfamily{lmr}\fi\selectfont}\relax



%(E)
\newfontfamily\myrmlat[Mapping=tex-text3,Colour=blue]{Noto Serif}
\newfontfamily\myttlat[Mapping=tex-text3,Colour=green]{Noto Sans Mono}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{latin}
{\ifx\f@family\btt@@name\myttlat
\else\myrmlat\fi}\relax
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\rowcolor{blue!7}
Character & now maps to & instead of \\
\hline\\
\Large\textasciigrave & 
\Large ` & 
\Large\symbol{8216} \\
\Large\textasciigrave\textasciigrave &  
\Large `` & 
\Large\textquotedblleft \\
\Large\textquotesingle & 
\Large ' & 
\Large\symbol{8217} \\
\Large\textquotedbl & 
\Large " & 
\Large\textquotedblright \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
so that 
`x' = 'x',``y" = "y".


\section*{Section 1}
I said,```মানুষ মাত্রই ভুল করে' - এটাকে ইংরেজিতে অনুবাদ কর".\\
He replied, ```To err is human' - It's an easy one. আরো কঠিন কিছু জিজ্ঞেস করেন".

\section*{Section 2}
I said,"'মানুষ মাত্রই ভুল করে' - এটাকে ইংরেজিতে অনুবাদ কর".\\
He replied, ```To err is human' - It's an easy one. আরো কঠিন কিছু জিজ্ঞেস করেন''.

\section*{Section 3}
I said,``ইংরেজিতে অনুবাদ কর - `মানুষ মাত্রই ভুল করে'".\\
He replied, ```To err is human' - It's an easy one. আরো কঠিন কিছু জিজ্ঞেস করেন".

\end{document}
````

Comment: Note that the web page is doing its own mapping: `y''` becomes `'y''`.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for the answer!